# jMeter Slave - Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. ip-10-142-111-66 is a loopback address

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I created a barebones ec2 ubuntu server with only jmeter installed using hte following..

```
sudo apt-get install jmeter
```

This server is designed to be the slaves.  when I run sudo jmeter-server I get the below error.  This error leaves me with no where to go since its a bare bones ubuntu server and as far as I know the jmeter apt-get install installs all of the dependancies.  I have seen this post but still vague on won to fix the issue.

[JMeter - Loopback address error when launching jmeter-server on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150448/jmeter-loopback-address-error-when-launching-jmeter-server-on-linux)

```
   sudo jmeter-server
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate commons-net in /usr/share/java
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-activation-1.1-spec in /usr/share/java
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate geronimo-javamail-1.4-provider in /usr/share/java
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate jboss-j2ee in /usr/share/java
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: Unable to locate jdom1 in /usr/share/java
    [warning] /usr/bin/jmeter: No JAVA_CMD set for run_java, falling back to JAVA_CMD = java
    java.lang.Throwable: Could not access /usr/share/jmeter/lib/junit
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.<clinit>(NewDriver.java:96)
    Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.1.1:56808](local),objID:[22c4bd9a:13773cb6090:-7fff, 2168779335812031976]]]
    Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. ip-10-142-111-66 is a loopback address.
```

Comment: My answer can solve that problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150448/jmeter-loopback-address-error-when-launching-jmeter-server-on-linux/17937883#17937883

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar issue and I abandon the ubuntu packaged version of jmeter for a newer version.

You can find them here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/

I was able to start a server like so:

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.8.tgz
tar -xzf apache-jmeter-2.8.tgz 
export RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
apache-jmeter-2.8/bin/jmeter-server
```

NOTE: This also gets around the issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150448/jmeter-loopback-address-error-when-launching-jmeter-server-on-linux)

Answer (score 3):

I remember hitting an issue like this.

What is in your /etc/hosts file on the slave jmeter box?

Maybe try changing this

```
127.0.1.1 <your server name> localhost
```

To this

```
127.0.1.1 localhost
```